# "there are 2 elements that match the criteria" error in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, automation, anaconda, spyder, pywinauto

**Goal**: I'm trying to automate Canva.exe to create designs via GUI automation.

**Specs**: *Spyder V5* (via anaconda) and *Python 3.8* on  *Windows 11 Home OS*

**Problem:** pywinauto is finding duplicate target values for the last 2 lines of my code (below) and giving me the error message (also included below).

Code:

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application 

CanvaWin = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Canva', timeout=100) 
#CanvaWin.Canva.print_control_identifiers()

YP = CanvaWin.Canva.child_window(title="Your projects",control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
YP.click_input()


UP = CanvaWin.Canva.child_window(title="Uploader", control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
UP.click_input()


VT = CanvaWin.Canva.child_window(title="1 OF 2 More actions VideoTemplate Presentation", control_type="Button").wrapper_object()
VT.click_input()

time.sleep(10)

#CanvaWin.Canva.print_control_identifiers()

ETT = CanvaWin.Canva.child_window(title="enter title", control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
ETT.click_input()
```

Error Message:

```
ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'title': 'enter title', 'control_type': 'Text', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Canva', Chrome_WidgetWin_1, 198500>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

Comment: Also posted here: https://coderanch.com/t/750858/languages/fix-elements-match-criteria-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/#:~:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20stop%20judging,work%20than%20posting.

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple elements matching your criteria, you can select one of them by adding `found_index` parameter to `child_window`-method:

```
ETT = CanvaWin.Canva.child_window(title="enter title", control_type="Text", found_index=0).wrapper_object()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - I'll try that later today!